# How to edit Grub from live usb / switch to safe graphics

Tags: grub2, usb, graphics

I Installed Ubuntu 20.10 (from 18.04 - fresh install) in safe graphics, because I was having video issues (the screen gets scambled after the disk check). After the install, I get the same scrambled sreen and I cannot access the grub menu by pressing the right (or left, or both) Shift key.

I would like first to be able to effectively change the value in the grub file to

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

from 0.

Using the Live USB, I am able to mount SDA2 on my machine

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

and edit the grub file,

```
$ sudo nano /mnt/etc/default/grub
```

but when I submit the command `$ sudo update-grub` , I get the following:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error:failed to get canonical path of '/cow'
```

I am way out of my confort zone here, Please advise how I can do this.

The second part of my question would be to set my grub to be in safe graphics mode by default. From looking on the internet, I beleive I need to have the `nomodeset` put in the grub file, but I have no idea how to go about it.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your /cow is your live installer Copy on Write. You have to chroot into system to run commands on system. Or use Boot-Repair which walks you thru a minimal chroot. But you should be able to bring grub up when booting with escape key if UEFI or shift if BIOS.  But if you have grub set for 0 then that will not work. And you should only need nomodeset to boot once as booting, not as a setting in grub. You can violate rule that says never to edit /boot/grub.cfg to change settings, but then any update will overwrite those changes. But then you should be able to boot and update from wtihin system.

Comment: You should run `sudo update-grub` when you have booted into the installed system (do not run it in the live system). If you need `nomodeset` and/or other boot options already at boot (before running `sudo update-grub`) in your *installed* system, you can add it temporarily at the grub menu (by pressing the 'e' key and then add it near the end of the 'linux line'. See [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808).

Comment: Have you tried running from the Live Usb then running Boot Repair?

Comment: Thank you all for your prompt response. I did try the Boot-repair. Despite stating no errors, I still do not get the grub and after the normal boot, the display goes crazy and I cannot operate the machine. Here is the pastebin contents: [link]http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/52pVZCbfQs/

Answer (score 0):

Boot repair did it for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Coditoergosum There is no other answer to accept. This is the unique self-answer by the author of the question.

Comment: @Coditoergosum It's not someone, it's some*thing*. The options in the review queue add comments like this one automatically. No comments are added automatically if you don't select any of the options when you choose *Recommend deletion* when reviewing an answer.